# sort an array by key and by value too in PHP

Tags: php

How to sort an array by ascending key and descending value?
[image]

Comment: do you try ksort?

Comment: You mean: Sort by value descending and **then** by key ascending?

Comment: yea. That's exactly what I need.

Comment: ksort ignores values

Comment: Why is 7 after 9 and 80 after 82? What's the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1):

```
    array_multisort(array_values($array), SORT_DESC, array_keys($array), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Comment: The shorter version of the thing you did is `rsort($array)`. try it!

Comment: @p01ymath, In this way, it loses the original value of the key.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need `array_values`.

Comment: @TsV The first time I tested it worked. He did not lose the value of the keys. Now, with the same values ​​as the previous test, it loses. This happened after I tested KSORT.

Comment: @JetroBernardo, this way too, it will lose the value of keys. I already tested it before commenting.

Comment: I can not find a solution for this case.

Comment: Solved here: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361111/como-classificar-array-pela-chave-e-pelo-valor-sem-perder-o-valor-original-da-c#361115

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you are looking for.

```
<?php
$array = array(5=>100,4=>100,3=>100,1=>100,8=>97,6=>97,9=>82,7=>80);

$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);

sort($keys);
rsort($values);
for($i=0;$i<=count($keys)-1;$i++){
    $array[$keys[$i]] = $values[$i];
}
?>
```

Comment: thus, the key is decreasing

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved in Stack in Portuguese, in the following link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361111/como-classificar-array-pela-chave-e-pelo-valor-sem-perder-o-valor-original-da-c#361115